# Trait in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to use traits in CodeIgniter. I put the Trait in the libraries directory and then loaded the library in the controller. Then I used the trait in the model, but it didn't work and I received the following error

Trait file (in library):

```
trait DataTablesTrait{
    public function query(){
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->limit(10, 1);
        return $this->db->get('my_table');
    }
}
?>
```

Controller:

```
class myController extends CI_Controller {  

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('DataTablesTrait');
        $this->load->model('ABC_Model');
    }
}
```

Model:

```
class ABC_Model extends CI_Model {
    use DataTablesTrait;
    function callQuery(){
        $this->query();
    }
}
```

I got this error:

> Non-existent class: DataTablesTrait

Please advise

Comment: If CodeIgniter doesn't feature an autoloader use `include` to include the file that contain the trait into the file that uses it. Or switch to a modern framework.

Comment: @axiac Thank you. Include work fine.
 I can't switch to another framework, the system already built using Codeigniter.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

CodeIgniter (CI) isn't `trait` or `namespace` friendly but they can be used. It requires working around CI a bit though.

The main problem, the CI thing you have to work around, is the call

```
$this->load->library('DataTablesTrait');
```

CI will find this file but `load->library` will try to instantiate the trait which fails because it is not possible to instantiate a Trait on its own.

Replace the line above with

```
include APPPATH.'/libraries/DataTablesTrait.php';
```

You should be free of the error with that. But you're not going to get results because `callQuery()` does not return anything. To round out the test have `callQuery()` return the `CI_DB_result` object the Trait should produce

```
public function callQuery()
{
    return $this->query();
}
```

Add an index function to the controller so we can dump the output

```
public function index()
{
    $DB_result = $this->ABC_Model->callQuery();
    var_dump($DB_result->result());
}
```

This should produce the expected output - assuming that 'my_table' has data :)

Comment: Thank you :)
This work fine:   include APPPATH.'/libraries/DataTablesTrait.php';

Comment: i found out by default system will load library from the system->library.. but this one helped me alot

Comment: This answer pertains to CodeIgniter 3.x and earlier. CI versions 4.x and newer do not require the workaround shown.

Answer (score 1):

Worth saying that `traits` are now fully supported in Codeigniter 4 and can be implemented as you would expect using namespaces etc.

```
// TRAIT
namespace App\Controllers\traits;

trait YourTraitName {

}

// CONTROLLER
use App\Controllers\traits\YourTraitName;

class Admin extends BaseController {

    use YourTraitName;
```

Comment: And what about Codeigniter 3?